# Squid Proxy - The requested URL could not be retrieved

Tags: proxy, iptables, squid

I'm trying to redirect all of my subnet traffic to a squid proxy using iptables on the router gateway (the squid proxy is located in the LAN).

The redirection works (cache & access file respond well), but the requested page page shows an error (image is attached)

Squid version:3.5.27
The iptables lines that we used for the redirection:
192.168.0.110:3129
- the squid box port+IP.
192.168.0.1
- the router's IP.

**iptables**:

1. `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.110:3129`
2. iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.110
    --dport 3129 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1

**squid.conf**

These are the lines that we have changed/added to the `squid.conf`:

```
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/24

http_access allow localnet 
http_port 3129
```

[image: error img]
I can't figure it out where is the problem (iptables or `squid.conf` file). 
Thank you in advance.
Chat Conversation End
Type a message...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to configure a transparent proxy, so I guess you just miss the transparent argument to your http_proxy settings. Modify the line with the following syntax:

```
http_port 3128 transparent
```

Restart the service and try again.

Comment: I added this to my config file also added another forward proxy port (3128), got this errors in the cache.log file:
NF getsockopt(ORIGINAL_DST) failed on local=192.168.0.110:3129 NAT/TPROXY lookup failed to locate original IPs on local=192.168.0.110:3129 and the browser shows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE